# sharepoint add-in multi site installation

Tags: sharepoint, office-addins, officedev, sharepoint-addin

developing a provider hosted application where the application redirects to different pages of a web application hosted on an azure web site.
This web site also handles the app installed event.
The problem is that in the web.config of the site, we need to add a client ID and Password, but these (Client ID/Password) are automatically generated by the SharePoint Online app registration page, after we register the application on the SharePoint online site.

So if we install the app on this SPOnline Site , it works fine, but if we try to install it on another site, when it redirects to the azure web site page, we got an authentication error.

need to add a unique client ID and password to the azure web site so when the SharePoint app in being installed on any Client ‘s SharePoint site can be identified as safe, authenticated and well-functioning with the azure site.
In the current process, we have to create an azure web site for each SharePoint Site where the application is being installed

How is this done with SharePoint plugins? Does the provider have to generate the Id and secret on each SharePoint Site.
In the SharePoint web provider project code , I found something called HostedAppSigningKey and HostedAppName , but did not find any tutorial about that. Can these be used for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple environments you should generate a id/secret from the [Microsoft Seller Dashboard](https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Keys) (even if you don't plan to sell your add-in) and use one set for all the environments. You should not use the appregnew page.

Comment: So this will give a multi-tenant id/secret, as the dashboard is a paid service. we wanted to confirm this before paying for the service

Comment: The dashboard is free, they only take a percentage if you publish paid apps via the dashboard. But you can get just the ID and secret from the dashboard without paying for anything.

Comment: Once you click on sign up, you are redirected to payment page. which is the old way forward.

Comment: It's probably just a confirmation with a valid credit card to make sure you're a "real person". All Microsoft marketplaces used to have that a long time ago. As I'm already signed up for most of them I cannot confirm or not if it's still the case.